# Connecting to constrained endpoint failing in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am playing around with constrained endpoints on a test VM and did the following:

- Created **TestUser** local account (only part of the Users group)
- ran the following:

  `New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path c:\test.pssc -ModulesToImport smbshare
  -PowershellVersion 3.0 -VisibleFunctions 'get-smbshare'
  -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer`
- registered endpoint using:

  `Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Path c:\test.pssc -Name test
  -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -AccessMode remote -RunasCredential Administrator`
- try to connect to it using:

  `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName test -Credential TestUser`

I go through everything and it works until the connection attempt. It says access denied. The PS shell is running as admin. I've given the TestUser read and execute rights to the endpoint per the remote_troubleshooting documentation. If I run the command without the credential parameter or pass in an admin username, it connects fine... what am I missing here?

Comment: Could you review your question for typos, e.g. `Register-PSSessionConfiguration - patch c:\test.pssc`; looks like that should be `-Path`. It does help prevent confusion or guessing.

Comment: In the examples where you show use of `-Credential` or `-RunAsCredential` the username is just a string. I would expect you to provide a PSCredential object (i.e. as a variable, obtained via `$cred = Get-Credential`). If you expect to give (just) a username as a string, maybe that's why it isn't working; when you don't specify that switch it will just take the current user's credentials.

Comment: ahhh thank you. I will test that out tomorrow and report back. As for your first comment, yeah my mistake i am using -Path

Comment: @CharlieJoynt so i tested your recommendation by creating two variables, $admincred and $usercred, both set to get-credential. In the command to establish the connection, i passed in those objects and now im getting an odd error..."Cannot perform operation because operation "SetLocation" is not valid. Remove operation "SetLocation", or invesitgate why it si not valid"..google has not proved useful so far. Not sure if you've come across this before.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished sorting out how to get the local admin account to work with a remote session.

1. I had to use an authentication mechanism of "Negotiate". Kerberos is the default auth mechanism, but it doesn't work for local accounts.
2. The target machine has to be add to the WinRM Trusted Hosts on your workstation. This seems to be a consequence of using Negotiate instead of Kerberos.
3. The local account must be added to the local group the local group WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_ on the target machine.

In this instance, the session needed to run with elevated permissions, and I had to add a DWORD registry subkey "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolciy" to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System with a value of 1 to allow creation of a security token with elevated privileges for a local account being used remotely. Since you're using a delegated session you probably won't need to do that.

Comment: hmmm, im just using localhost as a test for "remoting" but I made the changes you suggested, added the computer to the list of winRM trusted host with Set-item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -value localhost, added the local user to the WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_ group...created a new endpoint, tried connecting to it using the local user account credentials and im still getting the same errorr above...maybe im doing something wrong. On the domain, access is denied, off the domain, i get the SetLocation error.

Comment: also when trying to connect, I am using the -authentication parameter and passing in Negotiate

Comment: Are you doing all of this from the same machine?

Comment: yes i am, it works if i remove the -credentials parameter or if i pass in a user with admin rights, just not when im testing this with an account that doesn't have elevated priviledges. When i read the documentation for these commands, it says if you give the local user account read and execute rights, you should be able to delegate access to that user to run the commands in the session configuration file.

Comment: Then I can't vouch for the information I posted being helpful.  It wasn't tested in that environment.